# Linux USB programming

Tags: c, linux, usb, kernel

I am new to Linux kernel programming. I wish to develop a program to read USB drive information like its manufacturer name, capacity, etc. I know about descriptors and their attributes. But I don't understand how to enumerate USB drives connected to the system. I am looking for the function which initiates connection between kernel and USB port. How is it possible?

Comment: It's funny how the most OS-specific topic ever (driver creation) mentions no OS.

Comment: Very similar to this, posted by Jay rather than Jau: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452625/linux-kernel-programming

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention.It's on Linux

Comment: I know. that time I thought my code was proper for detecting removable drives but then I realised it could detect only one drive

Comment: You don't need to go digging through the kernel for this information, use libusb for these kinds of things.

Comment: @Jau - don't know if you have enough rep to edit your own title, but this might make more people find (and answer) the question

Comment: I had used libusb but it as far as I know it doesn't have provision to find drive space and capacity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to program the kernel as such - in fact to read the device info you don't even need a device driver.

The USB system is different in the newer 2.6 kernels so a lot of the online tutorials may be out of date - but start here http://www.linux-usb.org/

If you do want to write a USB device driver see this [Linux journal tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7353)

Answer (score 4):

Do you really want to do a kernel programming? There is an lsusb utility, capable of reading "USB drive information like its manufacturer name", descriptors... It also can enumerate all usb devices.

Sources of `lsusb` are e.g. here http://www.google.com/codesearch#VKTEFMx6wp0/lsusb.c

If you are doing a writing an USB driver, which works in kernel mode, I suggest you read some existing usb driver and USB driver programming FAQ.