# how to write a program to scan for the connected USB and show them in terminal

Tags: c, linux, usb

I was just wondering that if this possible to write a program in c in linux  to scan for the usb connected to the system and show them in terminal.

I have a good hand in shell scripting but dont know how to this in C program. In shell scripting, we can use echo command to do many functions but what is the replacement of echo in C language.

Any guide or a sample code will help, thanks.!

Comment: 1. This is very OS specific. 2. It's not very simple. 3. Google for cross platform usb library and check their api to see how to list devices. Also, if you are on linux, just use `lsusb`.

Comment: @iharob OS specific, i thought there might some functions. ok i'll google it. Thanks for comment

Comment: Try to read this: http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?popen+3. This is the way to get the echo of commands.

Comment: I'll be intersted in a good reply of someone that know how to obtain the result you want in a more specific way, but popen may help you (i think)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini I am also waiting for that. and sure i'll study about the link you have given. :)

Comment: @user3668172. See also this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456167/linux-usb-programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be funny! :) As you indicate in the question, I send you a way to get echo in a C program! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    char * buf;

    f=popen("lsusb", "r");
    if (f==NULL) {
        perror("1 - Error");
        return errno;
    }

    buf=malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    if (buf==NULL) {
        perror("2 - Error");
        pclose(f);
        return errno;
    }

    while(fgets(buf,BUF_SIZE,f)!=NULL) {
        printf("%s",buf);
    }
    puts("");

    pclose(f);
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be a shell script. And it's not very smart to do `buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);` when you could just do `char buf[BUF_SIZE];` and `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf) ...)`.

Comment: Yes I know, but is "requested" in the question!

Comment: It's not, the OP apparently wants a native way to do this, so if you are going to propose the use of `lsusb` a shell script will be 1e6 times more appropriate for the task, even a python script could be good. And you have to close the pipe with `pclose()`.

Comment: I've written this because the question says that the author don't know how to take the echo result in a C program! ... I know that is an OP question! ;)

Comment: @iharob yes shell script will do it easily but I want it in C program

Comment: I understand that @user3668172 wants manage the USB info using C, and this is a simple way to do that.

Comment: @user3668172 It's not for the interest of the question/answer but I am very curious, why do you want to do it in c? Try extracting parts of the information, if you don't have experience in c, it will be a lot harder than just running a program and echoing it's output.

Comment: @iharob I cannot use shell script because I have made the complete project in C only. Now just because its  easier to scan usb using shell script, i cannot make my whole project in shell script. Thats why I want it in C.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `libusb` which is a more robust way to do what you want, you need root privileges or at least read access to all the usb devices, you can create a *udev* [rule](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html) for that, this is the code

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    libusb_context *context;
    libusb_device **list;
    ssize_t         count;
    size_t          index;

    if (libusb_init(&context) != 0)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: intializing `libusb'");
        return -1;
     }

    count = libusb_get_device_list(context, &list);
    for (index = 0; index < count; ++index)
    {
        struct libusb_device           *device;
        struct libusb_device_descriptor descriptor;
        char                            buffer[256];
        struct libusb_device_handle    *handle;
        int                             result;

        device = list[index];
        if ((result = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &descriptor)) != 0)
         {
            fprintf(stderr, "error(%d): reading descriptor\n", result);
            continue;
         }

        if ((result = libusb_open(device, &handle)) != 0)
         {
            fprintf(stderr, "error(%d): openning device 0x%04X:0x%04X\n", 
                result, descriptor.idVendor, descriptor.idProduct);
            continue;
         }
        fprintf(stdout, "\ndevice #: %zu 0x%04X:0x%04X\n", 
            index, descriptor.idVendor, descriptor.idProduct);

        result = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(
            handle,
            descriptor.iProduct,
            (unsigned char *)buffer,
            sizeof(buffer)
        );
        if (result != 0)
            fprintf(stdout, "\tproduct     : %s\n", buffer);
        result = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(
            handle,
            descriptor.iManufacturer,
            (unsigned char *)buffer,
            sizeof(buffer)
        );
        if (result != 0)
            fprintf(stdout, "\tmanufacturer: %s\n", buffer);
        libusb_close(handle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

remember to pass `-lusb-1.0` to the linker command, or if you use a `Makefile` add it to `LDFLAGS`.

A simple *udev* rule to achieve that would be

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",MODE="0660",GROUP="usb"
```

adding your user to the **usb** group.

You could also write a simple `dbus` program that gives you access to this information, and share it with unprivileged users.

Comment: what if i want to see ls /dev, so that i can see ttyUSB connected to the system.?

Comment: You don't need `ls /dev/` just `DIR *dir = opendir("/dev");` and `readdir(dir)` until there are no more entries matching the `ttyUSB`.

Comment: Where do i need to add the line.?

Comment: @user3668172 what line?